# ALSAMIXER - deleted the alsa* from /bin - need to recover

Tags: alsa

I am an Archlinux user and I ve had problems with alsamixer which didn't play sound in google-chrome. So I 1st tried to uninstall it using:

```
sudo pacman -Rns alsa-plugins alsa-tools alsa-oss
```

After "removing" the alsa (so I ve thought) I could still call it using command `alsamixer` which is bizarre. So i tried ti completely remove it by changing my pwd into the `/bin` and using command:

```
sudo rm alsa*
```

which did seem to remove the alsa and the command alsamixer wasnt reckognized any more (file `.asoundrc` in my home folder was also removed by me):

```
[ziga@ziga-cq56 ~]$ alsamixer
bash: alsamixer: command not found
```

Then I tried to reinstall the same packets that I deleted and now I get:

```
[ziga@ziga-cq56 ~]$ alsamixer
bash: alsamixer: command not found
```

It is weird that Amarok music player still plays music. Can anyone help me recover alsa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably had alsa-utils and alsa-lib still installed. Remove them and then reinstall with 'alsa-plugins alsa-tools alsa-oss alsa-utils'. Alsa-lib should install automatically as a dependency of the others.

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. I didn't know about alsa-lib and that it was installed along other packages :) This allso fixed my previous audio errors